# ¿Por qué no me genera bien los consecutivos en MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

Buenos días estoy haciendo un curso de programación reactiva con Webflux, quise modificar un poco el ejemplo que dan poniendo un campo llamado consecutivo, veo que en MongoDB no hay consecutivos y lo que toca hacer en generarlos con una colección en donde se guarde el último consecutivo.

Tengo dos colecciones creadas: productos y contador_productos.

En la primera guardo unos datos simples sobre productos y en la segunda un consecutivo.

Estoy trabajando con Webflux con Reactor.

Tengo este código en un método Run ya que es de prueba por eso borro las colecciones y las vuelvo a crear cada vez que arranca la aplicación.

```
mongoTemplate.dropCollection("contador_productos").subscribe();
        ContadorProductos cp0 = new ContadorProductos();
        cp0.setConsecutivo(0L);
        mongoTemplate.insert(cp0, "contador_productos").subscribe();

        mongoTemplate.dropCollection("productos")
                .thenMany(Flux.just(new Producto("TV Panasonic Pantalla LCD", 459.89),
                        new Producto("Sony Camara HD Digital", 177.89),
                        new Producto("Apple iPod", 46.89),
                        new Producto("Sony Notebook", 846.89)))
                .flatMap(p -> {
                    return contadorDao.findAll()
                            .take(1)
                            .singleOrEmpty()
                            .flatMap(cp1 -> {
                                Long consecutivo = cp1.getConsecutivo();
                                p.setCreateAt(new Date());
                                consecutivo = consecutivo + 1;
                                p.setConsecutivo(consecutivo);
                                cp1.setConsecutivo(consecutivo);
                                return contadorDao.save(cp1)
                                        .then(productoDao.save(p))
                                        .thenReturn(p);
                            });
                })
                .subscribe(savedProduct -> {
                    log.info("Id: " + savedProduct.getId() + " Producto: " + savedProduct.getNombre() + " Consecutivo: " + savedProduct.getConsecutivo());
                });
```

El código anterior me crea las dos colecciones pero al momento de ver los productos todos tienen el consecutivo 1 y veo que también es el mismo en la colección "contador_productos".

Esta es la salida del log al final:

```
2023-05-24T09:23:32.815-05:00  INFO 21956 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication       : Started WebfluxApplication in 5.456 seconds (process running for 14.177)
2023-05-24T09:23:33.473-05:00  INFO 21956 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication       : Id: 646e1de57458af41ab586a2e Producto: Sony Notebook Consecutivo: 1
2023-05-24T09:23:33.635-05:00  INFO 21956 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication       : Id: 646e1de57458af41ab586a2d Producto: TV Panasonic Pantalla LCD Consecutivo: 1
2023-05-24T09:23:33.659-05:00  INFO 21956 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-5] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication       : Id: 646e1de57458af41ab586a2f Producto: Apple iPod Consecutivo: 1
2023-05-24T09:23:33.669-05:00  INFO 21956 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-6] c.e.webflux.app.WebfluxApplication       : Id: 646e1de57458af41ab586a2c Producto: Sony Camara HD Digital Consecutivo: 1
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hay una razón por la cual no se suele usar un campo `consecutivo` en MongoDB: no es necesario al NO SER una base de datos RELACIONAL. El campo `_id` (cuando es generado automáticamente por MongoDB) guarda un valor hexadecimal que puedes usarlo como aproximación al uso del campo consecutivo en SQL. Dicho esto, puedes implementar un campo de consecutivos en MongoDB, aunque mantenerlo suele ser algo complicado. Por ejemplo, si eliminas un documento intermedio en tu colección, ¿cómo afecta eso a los valores del consecutivo de todos los otros documentos?

Comment: En SQL esto tambíen implica un problema, por lo cual el campo consecutivo por lo general se usa en cierto tipo de casos de uso, por esta misma problemática. Al eliminar filas de las tablas, se crean huecos (`gaps`) en el consecutivo. Hay técnicas para solucionar este problema (manejo de `islas` y / o `huecos`). Pero la solución a este tipo de problemas siempre tiene un impacto en el rendimiento. Saludos